# What is the joint distribution of X and X+N if X and N are independent random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

We have two random variables X and N, on the same probability space, that are independent of each other. Then X+N will also be a random variable on the same probability space. What we are interested in finding out is what will be the joint distribution of the random variables X and X+N.

If we go by the definition,  it is nothing but
$$P(X \leq x, X+N \leq y) = P(X \leq x, N \leq y-X)$$

Can we use the fact that X and N are independent and simplify this further?

Answer (score 0):

You can use independence to write it as $\int F_X(\min \{x,y-t\})dF_N(t)$ where $F_X$ and $F_N$ are the distribution functions of $X$ and $N$ respectively.

Comment: Can we not write it in terms of the $P(X \leq x)$ and  $P(N \leq n)$ for some n?

Comment: No, it involves an integral ( an infinite sum in the discrete case).